# Union of intersections and intersection of unions - meaning

Tags: analysis, elementary-set-theory

Does anyone understand the meaning of this?
$$\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}\bigcap_{j=n}^{\infty} A_j$$

If this went to 5 for example instead of going to infinity, what would it look like?

Thank you.

Comment: Please don't use images to convey key information about your question (mathematical or otherwise). See [here for an explanation why](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/34123/742).

Comment: @311411: If you are going to edit a picture, don't just replace it with another picture, get rid of it altogether.

Comment: It's the set of elements that are in all but finitely many $A_j$.  Do you see why?  Can you prove it?

Comment: It would be a very different thing if it "went to $5$ instead of infinity", because unions distribute over intersections in the finite case, so you could rewrite this as just a bunch of intersections.

Comment: It's $\underset{n\to\infty}{\lim\inf}A_n$ - look, for example, Jacques Neveu - Mathematical Foundations of the Calculus of Probability, 1965, page 15 - event which occurs when all of the events $A_n$ with the exception of at most finitely many occur.

Comment: This is sometimes written as $\limsup A_n.$ If it is just to $5$ the set is $A_5.$ https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set-theoretic_limit